# For Airbrake 5, do I need to use Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sidekiq, airbrake

**Environment**

- I'm installing `Airbrake` on `Heroku` for a `Ruby` web app (not Rails).
- So [`Airbrake#notify` for `Airbrake`](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby) version 5 for `Ruby` sends a notification asynchronously.
- My worry is that if I don't use `Sidekiq` worker + `Redis`, then it might still be possible that calling `Airbrake#notify` might still slow down the app's response time depending on how it's used (whether in a Rails-like controller or some other part of the app).
- Besides overcoming the potential issue mentioned above, the other advantage of using `Sidekiq` worker + `Redis` to call `Airbrake#notify` I can think of is that `Redis` has a couple of persistence strategies so if the app crashes I can backtrack and look over the backed up error notifications from the `Sidekiq` queue.
- Whereas if I don't use `Sidekiq` + `Redis` and the app crashes, then there will be no backed up data....

**Questions**

- Does that mean I don't need to use `Sidekiq` + `Redis` (or some other equivalent database)?
- Am I understanding the issue correctly?  I don't have a very complete understanding of "pooled connections" and asynchronous processing, so this makes understanding what to do here a bit challenging.

Answer (score 1):

This is the class that sends async notices https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/blob/master/lib/airbrake-ruby/async_sender.rb

It's using standard ruby threads to send messages, so no background service should be necessary